# Error creating window handle when setting MdiChild property

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a parent form `frmParent` and two MdiChild forms (`frmChild1`,`frmChild2`).

When I do:

`frmChild1.Show()` from a button within frmParent the form displays correctly.

When I do:

```
Dim frmChild As New frmChild1()
frmChild.Show()
```

It still works correctly.

When I do:

```
Dim frmChild As New frmChild1()
frmChild.MdiParent = Me
frmChild.Show()
```

I get error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Error creating window handle.
```

I've looked in other places at this error and most of them suggest it's related to creating too many Handles or GDI Objects, but as you can see this is not the case:

[image: Handles and GDI Objects for process running in debug mode via VS2017]

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to diagnose the cause of this.

I also have another bug whereby frmChild1.Click events don't trigger, which I have a suspicion might be related (or maybe not!).

Any ideas on the window handle error? I have provided the stack trace below if it's useful:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
   at Application.frmParent.tsmiMdiChild1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \redacted_location\frmParent.vb:line 90
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at Application.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: You will have to provide more code. I tried to reproduce your problem from your description, but everything works fine.

Comment: Hm... I don't know what other code I could provide, short of the entire form's code which isn't really an option. Don't suppose there are any likely culprits I could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I found the answer. Hopefully someone else finds this useful.

I was doing:

```
Dim frmChild As New frmChild1()
frmChild.MdiParent = Me
frmChild.Show()
```

And then:

```
Private Sub frmChild_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Hide()

    'Other code

End Sub
```

Once I stopped hiding in the child form in its load event I no longer get the error.

I don't fully understand why the combination of setting MdiParent prior to `.Show()` and then the `Hide()` in child form's load event caused this problem (other than it's completely stupid). The reason this logic occurred in my code was due to oversight during some refactoring of how the forms were being loaded.

As for my other issue:

> I also have another bug whereby frmChild1.Click events don't trigger,
>   which I have a suspicion might be related (or maybe not!).

It turns out that if you set the `MdiParent` property after you call `.Show()` it doesn't seem to give focus to other child forms unless you click the titlebar (which I misinterpreted as mouse click events being swallowed).

Now that I am setting `MdiParent` prior to `.Show()` all is well again on both fronts.